# How do I force HighCharts to label every column?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a basic column chart, numbers for each year. It works fine, but if I make the window too small, it swallows half the years

[image]

There's clearly plenty of room to fit the odd years in, so how do I tell high charts to do that?

```
var allspending = [
    [2002, 591856],
    [2003, 839446],
    [2004, 848463],
    [2005, 1034755],
    [2006, 1569442],
    [2007, 1484477],
    [2008, 2280282],
    [2009, 3261702],
    [2010, 4132972],
    [2011, 5321516]
];

$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        }, 
        series: [{
            name: 'Dollars',
            data: allspending
        }]
    });
});
```

I've played with [steps](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.labels.step) and staggering, but I only want it to stagger when it really absolutely has to.

[See for yourself!](http://jsfiddle.net/amandabee/XFv4a/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set tickInterval and min value.

```
 xAxis:{
            min:2002,
            tickInterval:1
        },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XFv4a/9/

Answer (score 0):

Amanda, if you change the approach you pass the data you can get it

instead of a 2 dimensional array pass the data as a single dimensional array
replece

```
[
    [2002, 591856],
    [2003, 839446],
    [2004, 848463],
    [2005, 1034755],
    [2006, 1569442],
    [2007, 1484477],
    [2008, 2280282],
    [2009, 3261702],
    [2010, 4132972],
    [2011, 5321516]
];
```

with

```
[591856,839446,848463,1034755,1569442,1484477,2280282,3261702,4132972,5321516]
```

and use categories

```
xAxis:{
    categories: ['2002','2003','2004','2005','2006','2007','2008','2009','2010','20011']
}
```

Updated your jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XFv4a/6/)

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: It didn't occur to me that my 2d array was the culprit, but I'd definitely rather keep my data in a single array (for my own sanity). This is a somewhat pared down version of the actual chart.

Comment: In the approach I mentioned the xAxis becomes a category axis with labels '2002'-'2011' while the 2d array makes the xAxis a regular axis with values 2002-2011